# The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. I am getting error while sending mails through the DBMAIL(SQL 2005)

Tags: sql-server

I m getting the following error(The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2014-12-14T18:11:18). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
)) when I m try to send multiple mails through SQL Server 2008. But single email is delivered successfully.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I used `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';`  SQL delay function, now its working fine.

Comment: I am also getting the similar error in SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition.